# Using Rx, OnError clearing out observers

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a Subject that's doing some deserialization.  I thought I was being considerate by handling deserialization exceptions and calling OnError(ex) on my Subject just to notify clients.  However, I was a little surprised that calling OnError appears to disconnect all my observers.  Is that the intended behavior?  In my case, I'd like to offer up the exception so the client can log it if they want, yet keep going.  Can I not do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended. `OnError` is similar to `OnComplete` -- once you call it, you can't call `OnNext` anymore so there's no point in the observers sticking around. Consider the inverse: you can't continue to enumerate an `IEnumerator` once `MoveNext()` throws.

If you want this observable to keep going, you'll need to create a separate observable for errors.

Comment: This is a bummer, I just refactored a lot of code to use Rx, and that breaks this. Any way to overrule this behavior?

Comment: @tvde1 I'd post a new question with some sample code, to get ideas on how to refactor your error handling.

Comment: Nah it's all right, I'll throw a huge `AggregateException` :)